# How to know whether I'm running redhat linux or some other version?

Tags: linux

Konsole showing this when I gave the command uname -a

```
Linux sonyvaio-host 3.6.3.1-QOMO #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri oct 26 2:55:12 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
```

What does this whole thing mean?  And I want to know the process for installation of softwares. Everytime I download something, it ended up with saying this application wants to install packages.

What does package mean actually?

Comment: is it too hard to find the system information in the system menu?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you're going to want to be familiar with where the [documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/toc.html#English) for Fedora is (assuming you're not using Redhat Enterprise Linux, which you or your company would have paid for).  In particular, [package management](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/System_Administrators_Guide/part-Package_Management.html) is probably what you'll want to take a look at.

#### What is Package Management?

Package management basically refers to installing software in a manner that makes it organized and facilitates upgrades as well as clean removal of unwanted software (as opposed to running `make install` with source tarballs, which leave you needing to manually organize your sources if you want any hope for handling upgrades or removal).  A package (in the Redhat world, these are .rpm files) essentially contains either the source code or precompiled program you want to install, as well as instructions for installing it, as well as logging what took place so that later changes can be made.  The package management system keeps track of what is installed and where to facilitate its core role.

#### Which Version of Redhat am I running?

As for how to determine which version you're running,

```
cat /etc/issue
```

and/or

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

entered at a shell prompt should give you your answer.